# How to append DataFrame data when using Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

Streamlit with Dataframe add row into the table action and also download as csv by Button with still showing the dataframe on screen.

OP1: Using session_state (Best way to manage and applies for more)

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

# "st.session_state object:", st.session_state

if "df_result" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['df_result'] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['h1','h2'])


# st.write(st.session_state)

def onAddRow():
    data = {
            'h1':"something",
            'h2':"something",
        }
    st.session_state['df_result'] = st.session_state['df_result'].append(data, ignore_index=True)

st.button("Add row", on_click = onAddRow)

@st.cache
def convert_df(df):
   return df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
st.download_button(
    "Press to Download",
    convert_df(st.session_state.df_result),
    "file.csv",
    "text/csv",
    key='download-csv'
)
st.dataframe(st.session_state['df_result'])
```

OP2: Basic append on global parameters but it will reset view when take action download btn because it rerun.

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df_log = pd.DataFrame(columns=['h1','h2'])
df_log_process = st.dataframe(df_log)

for x in range(10):
    df_log = df_log.append(
        {
            'h1':"something",
            'h2':"something",
        }, ignore_index=True)

    df_log_process = df_log_process.dataframe(df_log)
```